# Error al actualizar Pods de proyecto

Tags: ios, macos, safari, cocoapods

Estoy tratando de actualizar los Pods de mi proyecto pero me dice que no se puede conectar, esto es lo que me aparece:

> AlxMrcers-iMac:~ alxmrcer$ cd /Users/alxmrcer/Desktop/proygym_fnl/gym
>
> AlxMrcers-iMac:gym alxmrcer$ pod update
>
> Update all pods
>
> Setting up CocoaPods master repo
>
> > [!] Unable to add a source with url
> >     `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`. You can try
> >     adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
> >
> > [!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in
> >     the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not
> >     using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of
> >     choice.

Cuando ejecuto el mismo comando en cualquier otra Mac, lo ejecuta sin problemas, ademas cuando abro el Chrome puedo entrar a cualquier página, pero si uso AppStore o Safari, me aparece

> **Safari no encuentra el servidor**

o

> **Imposible de conectarse a la tienda**

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas limpiar la caché de Cocoapods. Para ello escribe lo siguiente:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
```

Posteriormente, escribe:

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Ve a `~/.cocoapods/repos` y ejecuta `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`